# Solving $\ln|1+y|=\ln|x|-\ln|x+1|+c$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> How do I solve the following equation for $y$?
> $$\ln|1+y|=\ln|x|-\ln|x+1|+c$$

I want to get rid of the absolute values in a mathematically correct way.

Sorry if the format of the equation is incorrect, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is how to use MathJax. You should clearly state your motivation for asking this question, so that we can better help you ([how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). Can you think of any ideas to remove the natural logarithms?

Comment: I could take e raised to the ln power on both sides.

Comment: Yes, and can you continue?

Comment: No, I can't continue from there.

Comment: Where are you stuck then? Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I still have the absolute values after I take e raised to the ln power on both sides. I want to get rid of them.

Comment: There is no way to get rid of the absolute values unless you restrict the domain, such as $x > 0$. Why do you want to get rid of the absolute values?

Comment: I see! I checked the answer and it has no absolute values. I must have missed something then.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange to get
$$
|1+y|=\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}e^c.
$$
then if $y>-1$ you get
$$
y=-1+\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}e^c
$$
and if $y<-1$ you get
$$
y=-1-\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}e^c
$$
in which for both cases $x\neq 0,1$.

To get rid of $|x|$ you can use $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ or then you split the intervals of $x$ by
$$
\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}=\frac{x}{x+1}
$$
when $x>$ or $x<-1$ and
$$
\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}=-\frac{x}{x+1}
$$
when $-1<x<0$.

Comment: It seems you are losing a (real) solution when squaring. Set $C=\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{\lvert x+1\rvert} e^c$, then $\lvert 1+y\rvert=C$ or $1+y=\pm C$ or $y=-1\pm C$

Comment: That big $C$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: I think you wrote your comment while I was fixing typos.

Comment: "square and take logarithm": taking the logarithm is useless here.

Comment: @MikaelHelin your solution is not correct. In $2\ln(1+y)$ you silently assume that $1+y>0,$ which is not necessarilly. Also, you first put away logarithmes to return back to them ... in an incorrect way. I am sorry but I am going to downvote your answer, so that the (+1) you have now does not mislead the readers.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks for politely commenting. You get an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiate both sides to get

$$|1+y| = \frac{|x|}{|x+1|}e^c.$$

Since $c$ is an arbitrary constant, so is $e^c$, so rename it $A$,
but note that $A$ is positive because it's equal to $e^c$.  So we have

$$|1+y| = A\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}.$$

If you remove the absolute values, you get a $\pm:$

$$1+y = \pm A\frac{x}{x+1}.$$

One $\pm$ does the job for both sides.  Now here the magic:
But simply declaring that $A$ is no longer just positive, but
can take negative values, you don't need the $\pm$ anymore. We'd say that $A$ absorbs the $\pm.$

$$1+y =A\frac{x}{x+1}.$$

Subtract $1$ from both sides and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!